# Bug with content control

Tags: office-js

If I insert content control and add new line after it, I can't resume writing on previous line. My cursor is inside content control so I have to write inside.

I know I can click right arrow on keyboard to get out of it, but this may not be intuitive for users.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

I've created video demonstration of the bug [here](https://youtu.be/gKSh-PllFwY).
Also, I've created sample project to reproduce this bug on [Github](https://github.com/Vj3k0/content-control-bug).

Comment: I can reproduce this with a manually added text content control. If the content control is at the end of a line, there is no way to put the cursor to the right of the control. So this isn't really an issue for the Office.js, or the extensibility platform. If this is a bug, it is a bug in the product. I will see if I can find out what to do in a case like this and provide an answer.

Comment: Hello Rick, any progress on the issue?

Comment: I filed a bug for the manually added content control.